# Socket.io broadcast to room not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io

In a node.js application using `"socket.io": "^2.0.4"`

Socket.io is initialized like this :

```
export let io: any;

 io = socketio(server,
    {
      secure: secure,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  );

  io.set('origins', '*:*');
  io.origins('*:*');

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('message', async (data) => {
    }
  }
```

I want to broadcast `message` to all socket in a room

So I did :

```
io.to(roomName).emit('message', data);
```

I logged after  io().to().emit() with no issue the roomName and data are ok

But no event pass in `message`, what am I missing ?

Comment: Too little code to perceive the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your sockect.IO configured properly on the server side, Here is a Low level socket service api based on rxjs for Angular that works and you can use

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as socketio from 'socket.io-client';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {

  private socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;
  connected$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() {
    this.socket = socketio(environment.socket.baseUrl, environment.socket.config);
    this.socket.on('connect', () => this.connected$.next(true));
    this.socket.on('disconnect', () => this.connected$.next(false));
  }

  join(room: string) {
    // auto rejoin after reconnect mechanism
    this.connected$.subscribe(connected => {
      if (connected) {
        this.socket.emit('join', {room});
      }
    });
  }

  disconnect() {
    this.socket.disconnect();
    this.connected$.next(false);
  }

  emit(event: string, data?: any) {

    console.group();
      console.log('----- SOCKET OUTBAND -----');
      console.log('Action: ', event);
      console.log('Payload: ', data);
    console.groupEnd();

    this.socket.emit(event, data);
  }

  listen(event: string): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable( observer => {

      this.socket.on(event, data => {

        console.group();
          console.log('----- SOCKET INBOUND -----');
          console.log('Action: ', event);
          console.log('Payload: ', data);
        console.groupEnd();

        observer.next(data);
      });
      // dispose of the event listener when unsubscribed
      return () => this.socket.off(event);
    });
  }

}
```

This code is from  **Avatsaev** all thanks to him for  sharing his cool app using socket Io with NGRX, you can see how its used with [his service code](https://github.com/avatsaev/angular-ngrx-socket-frontend/blob/master/src/app/views/notes/services/notes.service.ts)

Comment: The thing is, I configured socketIo on the server side too and already use it with no issue for simple socket to socket messages, or socket to room. But in this case `io to room` I can't make it work and I don't see why.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
socket.broadcast.to(roomName).emit('message', data);
```

More information: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#

Comment: I can't use that method because I have to make the call outside of io. The broadcast don't comes from a socket

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having a similar issue, make sure that you are emitting the message to the correct namespace. In my case, I needed to emit to the "chat" namespace where all the clients were listening, but just to a specific room.

For instance:

```
// We still need to specify the namespace, in my case, the "chat" namespace. This is where my clients are listening.
socket.on("special-message", (message) => {
  console.log("Special message is: ", message);
  socket.to("special").emit("chat", message); // Emit to "special" channel inside the "chat" namespace.
});
```

Comment: Hmm... "chat" here is the event name, not the namespace